# Whether Struts Action class can hold multiple create() methods

Tags: rest, struts2

I have a Struts action class which implements `ModelDriven`, and the methods `create()` and `index()` will be called based on the request type.

Can I have multiple `create()` methods with a way to differentiate or Is that not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a method with exclamation sign `!`. According to

[**RESTful URL Mapping Logic:**](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/rest/#restful-url-mapping-logic)

> This Restful action mapper enforces Ruby-On-Rails REST-style mappings. If the method is not specified (via '!' or 'method:' prefix), the method is "guessed" at using REST-style conventions that examine the URL and the HTTP method. Special care has been given to ensure this mapper works correctly with the codebehind plugin so that XML configuration is unnecessary.

If you let the action mapper to determine the method according to parameters

> ### This mapper supports the following parameters:
>
> - `struts.mapper.idParameterName` - If set, this value will be the name of the parameter under which the id is stored. The id will then be removed from the action name. Whether or not the method is specified, the mapper will  try to truncate the identifier from the url and store it as a parameter.
> - `struts.mapper.indexMethodName` - The method name to call for a GET request with no id parameter. Defaults to `index`.
> - `struts.mapper.getMethodName` - The method name to call for a GET request with an id parameter. Defaults to `show`.
> - `struts.mapper.postMethodName` - The method name to call for a POST request with no id parameter. Defaults to `create`.
> - `struts.mapper.putMethodName` - The method name to call for a PUT request with an id parameter. Defaults to `update`.
> - `struts.mapper.deleteMethodName` - The method name to call for a DELETE request with an id parameter. Defaults to `destroy`.
> - `struts.mapper.editMethodName` - The method name to call for a GET request with an id parameter and the edit view specified. Defaults to `edit`.
> - `struts.mapper.newMethodName` - The method name to call for a GET request with no id parameter and the new view specified. Defaults to `editNew`.

the method name can't have multiple names.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So I can't have multiple methods and have to use one of the listed above, else I have to create a new controller. Is that what you are trying to say?